# Specifying a non-.NET dependency in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll, dependencies

I'm calling a non-.NET dll from my project using P/Invoke, meaning that the .dll must always be present in the .exe's directory.

Is there any way to tell Visual Studio of this dependency, so that it will automatically copy the .dll to the output directory when compiling, and will automatically include the .dll in the setup? Or do I have to do this manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy/link this file(s) to the project, and in properties windows set "Build Action" to "None" and "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer" or "Copy always".

Or you can use a "Pre-Build Events" & "Post-Build Events" where you can specify any batch scripts.

I prefere the second option, because this way is more flexible than the first.

Also you can modify a MSBuild file and add a task for copy the file(s).

Comment: Thanks, the first option is what I was doing - wondered if there was a better way

Answer (score 8):

You can simply add the .DLL to your project.

Select the `Properties` pane for that file and set `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`.

Comment: Build Action = "Content" is better than Build Action = "None" suggested in another response.  This is because you can easily include "Content" files in a Setup project.

Comment: Yes, and that is exactly why I suggested that in my response.

Comment: > that is exactly why I suggested that in my response

And why I upvoted your answer:)

Answer (score 2):

I think one problem with just adding a .DLL to the project is that you may need different versions of a DLL for debug and release builds.  You'd think you can add both debug and release versions of the DLL to the file, and based on configurations, exclude the inappropriate one, but I couldn't find a way to do that.  I'm using Visual Studio 2010.  I am positive this worked in the old days with VS6.

Comment: You can manually edit the .csproj file to add a Condition to the DLL's content node:

    <Content Include="MyDLL.Debug.dll" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' " />
    <Content Include="MyDLL.Release.dll" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' " />

Alternatively, you could use a pre-build step to copy either MyDLL.Debug.dll or MyDLL.Release.dll to MyDLL.dll depending on the current configuration. (I think you should be able to do this through the Project properties page in VS, by switching from Debug to Release)