# Are there any better ways to copy a native dll to the bin folder?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, build, post-build-event

I have C# wrapper code that calls functions from a native (C++) dll. Currently, I can add a reference to the C# dll and have set the 'Copy Local' option to true. However the native dll, which is a dependency, cannot be added as a reference - so there is no 'Copy Local' option.

I have tried the following approaches

1. Using a post-build events to copy the native dll from the Libs folder to the `$(TargetFolder)`

   `copy "$(ProjectDir)Libs\NQuantLibc.dll" "$(TargetDir)NQuantLibc.dll"`
2. Included the native dll as an existing item in the project (Add -> Existing Item -> Include dll). This option allows me to use the 'Copy Local' option. The downside to this approach is that the dll always shows as a project item.

I also tried "Show All Files" which allowed me to see the Libs folder. I then include the NQuantLibc.dll file in the project which allowed me to set the 'Copy Local' option. However, this gave me a unexpected result. It created a Libs subfolder containing the dll within the bin folder (eg `bin/debug/Libs/NQuantLibc.dll`). Not ideal since the C# dll was not able to properly call the native dll since it was not there.

Both of the above options above work. Are there any better ways to copy a native dll to the bin folder such that the dependency will always be resolved? Alternatively, is there a different approach to this type of scenario?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126331/specifying-a-non-net-dependency-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use Project + Add Existing Item and select the DLL.  Select the added file in the Solution Explorer window.  In the Properties window, change the Copy to Output Directory setting to "Copy if newer".

Comment: I don't get the problem, it *is* a project item.  It won't run without it, just as it won't run when a source code file is missing.

Comment: @hans - i'm not saying there is a problem. I am only looking for a better way. There is one issue that I think is of concern. When adding the DLL as an existing item, a copy of the DLL is created in your project folder, thus if your original DLL ever gets updated, you will need to re-add it to the project. The post-build copy command in this case will be more robust IMO.

Comment: No it doesn't.  Note my advice: "Copy if newer".

Comment: @hans - tried that using a simple text file. Created `test.txt` with text "v1" in the Libs folder. Added the item to the project using the method described. A copy is created in the main project folder. Built the project and `test.txt` is copied to the bin folder as expected. Now I modified the contents of `test.txt` in the Lib folder and rebuilt. The file in the bin folder is still the old version.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Take a double-barreled shutgun and aim it between the disk platters.  Pull.  Problem solved.  This works on everybody's machine.  Good luck.

Comment: @hans - haha, I leave mine at the office. But seriously, if I'm being an idiot, I would appreciate clarification so I can learn from my mistakes.

Comment: I finally got it - what I did was follow the the initial idea and using a modified post build event similar to above ensured that the latest dll is in the bin folder.

Comment: @Ahmad: When adding the existing item in the dialog box watch out for the drop-down part of the "Add" button and change it to read "Add As Link". This is very easy to miss in the UI.

Comment: @nitrogenycs Thanks a lot. This should be stated more clearly in the answer.

Comment: Be *very* careful with "Add As Link".  That will likely not work anymore a year from now.  Or for that matter today on another machine.  Far too easy to forget to check-in the DLL into source control.

Comment: If you do not choose "Add As Link", you need make sure that you are adding the dll using the same folder structure within the project that you have on disk.  Otherwise, VS will make another copy of the dll.  My assumption for a scenario like this would be that the dll is checked into source control in a central location to be shared by multiple projects.  In that scenario, you don't want VS to make another copy within each project.  Adding as a Link allows you to update the centralized dll without touching all the projects that reference it.

Answer (score 21):

You can add the native dll as a linked item, and use "**Copy if newer**".
The problem with native dlls, is that sometimes you'll want to use different dlls according to the project's configuration (Debug/Release or platform).

You can edit the project's .csproj and link the native dll conditionally:

```
 <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|Win32' ">
    <Content Include="..\..\bin\Win32\Release\NQuantLibc.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
 </ItemGroup>   
 <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|Win32' ">
    <Content Include="..\..\bin\Win32\Debug\NQuantLibc_d.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64' ">
    <Content Include="..\..\bin\x64\Debug\NQuantLibc_d.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64' ">
    <Content Include="..\..\bin\x64\Release\NQuantLibc.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Note the copy option is set to **PreserveNewest** which means "copy if newer".

Comment: It's amazing that what used to be a main-line development pattern is now so odd-ball that you have to manually edit a .csproj file.

Answer (score 6):

Found a better way. Nuget can add .targets files, witch are stored in the build folder of the package, into your project. With this way you can copy at each build some files of your package wherever you want. In the following example, I have stored some Non DotNet DLL into a "binaries" folder. At each build, It checks if DLLs are already copied in the output folder ($OutputPath variable) and copy them if necessary.

**Nuspec content :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>Example</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <authors>Example</authors>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>Example</description>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="Non-DotNet.dll" target="binaries\Non-DotNet.dll" />
        <file src="DotNet.dll" target="lib\net40\DotNet.dll" />
        <file src="Example.targets" target="build\Example.targets" />
    </files>
</package>
```

**Example.targets content :**

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="CopyBinaries" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
        <CreateItem Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\binaries\**\*.*">
            <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="PackageBinaries" /> 
        </CreateItem>

        <Copy SourceFiles="@(PackageBinaries)"
              DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)"
              SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
              OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"
        />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the dll as a file in the project ("As link" maybe if u still want it to reside in another directory). Then set the Build Action to content and Copy to output directory to true.

Comment: Does this apply to VS 2010 Express? I can't seem to find the 'Add link' option. The remainder of the answers seems very similar to what was described in point 2. Am i mistaken?

Comment: @Ahmad you can add the file as link by pressing on the little downward arrow on the "Add" button (from Add → Existing item...), and selecting `Add as Link`

Comment: @hmemcpy - does not seem to work. Dll is not being copied to the bin folder and a corresponding exception is being thrown.

Comment: Actually it is being copied but to a Libs subfolder

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with the created "Libs" folder, you can try adding it to the [probing path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for your application, by adding the following in the `app.config` file:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="Libs;Bin2"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This will cause the runtime to look in all the specified directories for the DLL.

**EDIT** Unfortunately, this [does not impact the unmanaged DLL loading by DllImport](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/97418/dllimport-ignores-the-assembly-search-path-in-app-config).

Comment: I was busy on SO trying to find out why the exception was being thrown :(. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I happened to have the same problem, but I did not want to do project file editing so much, so I ended up using following post-build script:

`xcopy /y "$(ProjectDir)\lib_$(Platform)\*.dll" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)"`

Just make sure you have a folder for every targeting platform needed, e.g.: `lib_x86`, `lib_x64` and maybe `lib_AnyCPU`