# C# error: adding reference to .dll file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

I have my project file and Calculator01.dll file in same directory. When I'm trying to add a reference to Calculator.dll file message box appears and show

> "A reference to 'E\IT131344............Calculato01.dll could not be added. Please make sure file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

I have already marked class functions with in `CalDllWrapper` class;

```
[DllImport("Calculator01.dll")]
```

Solutions I have found so far does not work for me. What can I do to resolve this problem? Please help me.
thanks in advance

Comment: Calculator01.dll is not a .Net dll?

Comment: You don't need to add a reference in order to use DllImport.

Comment: @Viru It is C-based DLL. C/C++

Comment: @cubrr then how can i use DllImport?

Comment: right click on the dll file and go to properties, if in end of general tab, exist a button with unblock title, click that and retry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any better ways to copy a native dll to the bin folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863419/are-there-any-better-ways-to-copy-a-native-dll-to-the-bin-folder)

Comment: @Pegasus You just need to copy the imported DLL to the same directory as your executable (e.g. EugenePodskal's comment). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8861895/996081) for how the DllImportAttribute looks for the specified file.

Comment: @cubrr now it's working. thank you. DLL wasn't in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not add references to unmanaged DLLs. Only managed DLLs can be referenced. Unmanaged DLLs can only be used by using the `DllImport` attribute. Please note that the application needs to be able to access the DLL.