# VS2019: VB.NET to C: Unable to load DLL: HRESULT: 0x8007007E (worked in VS2017)

Tags: c, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

This question relates to Stackoverflow Question:
[Unable to load DLL (Module could not be found HRESULT: 0x8007007E)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003072/unable-to-load-dll-module-could-not-be-found-hresult-0x8007007e)

But I am not good enough to post comments there!

In **VS2017**, I have this VB.NET code which successfully calls a C DLL:

```
' MY_DLL: the simple [no path] DLL name
' *_STR: structs
' DLL_DIR: string, absolute directory path
<DllImport(MY_DLL, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> Public Sub MyCFunction(ByRef status As STATUS_STR, ByRef inputs As IN_STR, ByRef inOut As IO_STR, ByRef outputs As OUT_STR)
End Sub

Public Sub Call_MyCFunction(ByRef statRec As STATUS_STR, ByRef inputRec As IN_STR, ByRef ioRec As IO_STR, ByRef outputRec As OUT_STR)
    Dim holdDir As String = CurDir()
    ChDir(DLL_DIR) 'change directory to where the DLL lives
    FileSystem.CurDir() 'debugging

    'CALL THE "C" FUNCTION
    MyCFunction(statRec, inputRec, ioRec, outputRec) ' <== EXCEPTION THROWN HERE

    ChDir(holdDir)
    ...
```

This code worked until I upgraded to **VS2019.**
I now get the above error.

BUT:
I tried the kludge suggested in the related question - and it works!
If I hard-code the absolute path into

```
<DllImport(<absolute path to dll>, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> Public Sub MyCFunction(ByRef status As STATUS_STR, ByRef inputs As IN_STR, ByRef inOut As IO_STR, ByRef outputs As OUT_STR)
End Sub
```

I solve the problem.

**Any explanations?
I'd prefer to access the "C" function using my original tactic...**

**UPDATE**
The above issue occurred on a virtual machine.
The DLL in question resides on a network drive.
I've just installed the VS2019 solution on my own physical machine, and of course it works fine!

**Moderators:** Can delete this one if it is of no value.
Still curious tho'.

Comment: There's some pretty good advice at the Stack Overflow question you linked.

Comment: It is a bad idea, this code can only work when "safe DLL search" is turned off.  That is getting rare, it is quite a nasty code injection problem.  Do this [the right way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3864404/17034).