# Import and run a software in VB.net project

Tags: vb.net

I want to import and run a another app using `Process.Start`. But I cannot import exe files to my vb project. How do I do this... Again, I want to add another exe file to my project... I know how `Process.Start` works but it's only run  program out of this project.
Thank you

Comment: The best solution is to make DLL of that project and import it into your current project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3864404/17034, pick the EXE file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you have two options.

1. You can ship/pack/distribute the other exe with your programm. And just execute it from the path that your exe is runing from something like `IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly.Location) & "\Another.exe"`

or

2. You can embed the another file as a resource into your resources (My project/Resources/Add Resource/Add existing file). Distribute your single `exe`. And then save that internal resource (`My.Resources.YourFileName.Save(..)`) to some directory (like `IO.Path.GetTempPath`) and execute it with `Process.Start`

Comment: Please can you show me an example.. Because I'm new to VB.NET

Comment: Example of what? I tried to give you example of functions that you'll need.